# Is Microsoft Store the only way to distribute a self-contained UWP application?

Tags: c#, uwp, packaging

I've been trying to dig around a simple way to distribute this simple application I've created. I want things simple: a simple self-contained installer. Not to say that it cannot be put on the MS-Store, but I want alternative ways to distribute it simply to my clients.

I've create a package, but you need to enable the developers options to run it elsewhere.... And all the other solutions are either VERY costly or require a 3 year degree to understand them. And of course, the documentation on the internet is dominated by Microsoft who push their own solution, i.e. the Store.

I would be grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction please.

Comment: You can sideload a UWP app if that's what you are asking about: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/application-management/sideload-apps-in-windows-10

Comment: And many more posts: https://www.google.com/search?q=distribute+uwp+app+outside+store+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Yes, but distributing a side-load, if I'm not mistaken, is cumbersome. no?

Comment: Then don't use UWP.

Comment: @FrancoisGagnon: "Cumbersome" compared to what? You simply distribute a signed app package.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/dev-share/9nblggh51s0c

Comment: Oh! Thank you Shubham, that looks very promising!